# Three numbers are selected from {0,21} without replacement, for how many of them the sum of them is a multiple of 3?

Tags: algorithm

When I started solving this problem I came across this thought that multiples of three has this property sum of digits is a multiple of three. So for numbers less than 9. We can lay the condition that they must be numbers of a three digit numbers which is divisible by 3.

Comment: What do you mean by `{0, 21}`? Normally it would be a set of two things (the numbers 0 and 21) but that males no sense here. Do you mean the set of numbers from 0 to 21, inclusive? From 0 to 20? Something else altogether?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean 3 numbers are chosen from the range [0, 21] inclusive.

Look at the counts of numbers mod 3. You have 8 congruent to 0, 7 congruent to 1, and 7 congruent to 2.

Ways to get three that sum to a multiple of 3:

```
congruencies: count, example
0,0,0: choose(8, 3) = 56, e.g. 0 + 3 + 6 = 9
0,1,2: 8 * 7 * 7 = 392, e.g. 3 + 4 + 5 = 12
1,1,1: choose(7, 3) = 35, e.g. 1 + 4 + 7 = 12
2,2,2: choose(7, 3) = 35, e.g, 2 + 5 + 8 = 15
-------------------------
total: 518
```